# How do I import these three specific symbols from mathabx?

Tags: symbols, packages, package-options, mathabx

I would like to use the symbols `\smalltriangleup`, `\smalltriangledown` and `\blacktriangleup` from `mathabx`. The problem is that if I use the `mathabx` package, some of the other symbols change (like `\infty` and `\emptyset`). How could I use those three specific symbols without affecting the rest of the symbols?

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386) (Three symbols from the same font is nearly the same as one symbol.)

Answer (score 4):

Copy the relevant lines of the style file to your preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\smalltriangleup}   {2}{mathb}{"98}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\smalltriangledown} {2}{mathb}{"99}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\blacktriangleup}   {2}{mathb}{"9C}
\begin{document}

$a\smalltriangleup b\smalltriangledown c \blacktriangleup d$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To get the `mathb12` and `"98` values, look up mathabx's documentation: they list the character's code in tables at the end.

Comment: @Clément Useful advice for people passing by, thanks.