# How to use the symbol \blackdiamond from the mathabx package, without changing the appearance of other symbols?

Tags: symbols, mathabx

I need the `\blackdiamond` symbol (not `\bigLozenge`) in some equations; so I used the mathabx package. But, this altered other symbols such `\rightsquigarrow`. How can I use `\blackdiamond` without altering other symbols? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: There are known compatibility issues with the (very old) package `mathabx`. It redefines many commands for mathematical symbols. If you only need a handful of symbols from `mathabx`, it is advisable not to load it at all. You can import the individual symbols following the approach detailed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font/14388#14388), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622468/how-do-i-import-these-three-specific-symbols-from-mathabx/622472#622472) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323548).

Comment: Sorry, how do i "import"?? In the 2nd link, it seemed that the "98" in```\DeclareMathSymbol{\smalltriangleup}   {2}{mathb}{"98}``` decides the symbol; what number should I indicate for blackdiamond? Do I need to copy everything there? (I am asking because I dont want to change other symbols)

Comment: You are right, you need to pick the correct number for the desired symbol. Luckily, there is a [reference for mathabx](https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/fonts/mathabx/mathtest.pdf) with lists and tables. See my answer.

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are known compatibility issues with the (very old) package `mathabx`. It redefines aggressively a huge number of mathematical symbols, changing their appearance.

Therefore, it is advisable not to load `mathabx` at all, if you can help it. It is possible to import individual symbols from `mathabx`.

To do so, one can look up the desired symbol in the [mathabx command and symbol lists](https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/fonts/mathabx/mathtest.pdf). Then, one can import those symbols following the approach detailed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323550).

Assuming you only need the `\blackdiamond` (table `mathb`, number `0C`) and assuming that you want it to be a *binary operator* (the way it is defined in `mathabx`), here's the code for your preamble:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{<-5.5> mathb5 <5.5-6.5> mathb6 
<6.5-7.5> mathb7 <7.5-8.5> mathb8 <8.5-9.5> mathb9 <9.5-11> mathb10 
<11-> mathb12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\blackdiamond}{\mathbin}{mathb}{"0C}  % \mathbin for a binary operator
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Marquinho!! I have been at it the whole day. It works fine now. I appreciate your kind help.

Comment: @SphericalMoments You're very welcome! I remember my own frustration with this issue and with `mathabx`!

Comment: And in order to avoid wasting a math group for just one symbol, you could say `\DeclareRobustCommand{\blackdiamond}{\mathbin{\text{\usefont{U}{mathb}{m}{n}\symbol{"0C}}}}` removing `\DeclareSymbolfont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}`